# How long does it take before neutrino velocities in the neutrino background radiation are substantially less than the speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light, neutrinos, speed

The energy of photons is reduced by the expansion of space. Since the photons have been decoupled from matter their wavelengths have decreased from the visible range to the radio range.

The same should hold for the neutrinos that emerged from the big bang. They still travel at a speed that's close to the speed of light. Almost all their energy is kinetic.

Will their speed be reduced to, say, half the speed of light in the far future? If so, how long will that take?